# SPI Fanout Question

Tags: spi

I have a TM4C1294NCPDT microcontroller that is acting as an SPI master for 32 slaves. All of the traces fall within a 5 cm x 5 cm area, so the total trace length is ~20 cm. I will be clocking the SPI bus at 8 MHz.

Should I be concerned with fanout issues with SCLK? I'm not sure how I would go about calculating the capacitance on the line.

[image]

Comment: With this many devices I would be more concerned about the added input capacitance (should be in datasheet). I would probably sit down and calculate the expected impedances and make sure the rise and fall times are in spec. The large loop with ground plane probably doesn't help much and may add noise (about ~2-10pF as well). You may consider pulling down SCK (or up depending on your SPI) before resorting to a buffer. Other tips include terminating resistors.

Comment: @crasic Could you please explain more about the loop? Just to clarify, I have a four layer board. I chose to hide the ground and power layers for simplicity. I made sure that the SPI data lines do not form a loop (notice the break in connection in top-right corner). I thought that break would solve the loop issue.